# Jest encountered unexpected token when trying to test a React component using enzyme

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I got this error when trying to run a test on my Header component using shallow testing in Enzyme

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file that Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Details:

  4 |
  5 | test("should render Header correctly", () => {
> 6 |   const wrapper = shallow(<Header />);
    |                           ^
  7 |   expect(wrapper.find("h1").text()).toBe(1);
  8 | });
  9 |
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: You have to set a preset for react in your babel configs

Comment: @RafaelUmbelino i am using create-react-app how do i configure it ?!!

Comment: @EslamAllam follow this thread https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6933 solution.